# Issue with Spring boot twitter

Tags: spring, spring-boot, model-view-controller

I am trying to connect to twitter from Spring boot app.
I am adding the appId and appSecret values in my application.properties file. But I am getting an error "'spring.social.twitter.appID' is an unknown property.".

build.gradle file

```
buildscript {
ext {
    springBootVersion = '2.0.2.RELEASE'
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle- 
    plugin:${springBootVersion}")
}
 }  

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'masteringSpringMvc'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
 }


dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('org.springframework.social:spring-social-twitter:1.1.2.RELEASE')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

And below is application.properties file

```
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
spring.social.twitter.appID=apiKey
spring.social.twitter.appSecret=appSecret
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `spring.social.twitter.appId` instead of `spring.social.twitter.appID` (lower case 'd'). Source: https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-twitter/

Comment: Are you getting `spring.social.twitter.appId is an unknown property` (lower case) ?

Comment: yes I do get the error for both
spring.social.twitter.appId is an unknown property and spring.social.twitter.appSecret is unknown property

Comment: Try to follow Spring tutorial I posted above. Maybe you are missing something

Answer (score 0):

You can also use twitter4j to connect with twitter.
Here is the dependency
step:1

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.twitter4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>twitter4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>[3.0,)</version>
        </dependency>
```

step:2
Add twitter4j.properties file to your project then copy the credentials from twitter APP.

```
oauth.consumerKey=
oauth.consumerSecret=
oauth.accessToken=
oauth.accessTokenSecret=
```

Step:3
Create End Point

```
package com.reddit.clone.controller;


import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import twitter4j.Twitter;
import twitter4j.TwitterException;
import twitter4j.TwitterFactory;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/twitter")
public class TwitterController {


    @RequestMapping(value = "/tweet")
    public String getTweets() throws TwitterException {

        Twitter twitter = TwitterFactory.getSingleton();
        String message = "New Post";
        System.out.println(twitter.updateStatus(message).getText());
        return "";
    }

}
```